# How do I distort a vector image of a flag to make it look like it is draped off a flagpole?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a logo that I am vectorizing from a raster original.  Two of the components are flags - one is the US and the other is the State of Florida.  In the original, the two flags are flying/draped from flagpoles on either side of a central image.

I have the vector files for both flags, but I can't seem to find any information on how to distort/shear the images properly to recreate the original logo.  For your reference, here is the original file with the center image blurred (don't want to get in trouble with the client).

Thanks!

Scott
[image: Logo w/ Flags]

Comment: A convoluted way would be to apply it as a material to a plane in a 3D program like Blender. And export the resulting render

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best option will be `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh`.

Select desired number of rows and columns (with your example I would go with 10x10).

[image: First]

Manually position it as you want and go to `Object > Envelope Distort > Envelope` Options to change Fidelity.

[image: Second]